# How to make Holograms move relative to user's head in Hololens 2?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I am creating a simple App on Hololens2 using Unity. I create two game objects and want them to move based on the user's head movement i.e. they do not stay still at a place in space but move relative to the user's head. However, I am not sure on how to enable this setting. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

The [`Orbital Solver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/ux-building-blocks/solvers/solver?view=mrtkunity-2021-05#orbital) provided in MRTK can implement this idea without even writing any code. It can lock the object to a specified position and offset it from the player. It is recommend to refer to the SolverExamples.unity which is located at /MRTK/Examples/Demos/Solvers/Scenes to get stated  `Solver` components.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have a object at a specific distance from the HoloLens 2 at any given time.
So that (for example) a cube is always in the upper right corner of the users view.
If that is the case you can position the desired object as a child to the `Main Camera` (located under the `MixedRealityPlayspace`) in the hierarchy view.